# How to connect Java classes to GUI?

Tags: java, mysql, database, user-interface, windowbuilder

I'm designing a database that can be accessed through a GUI, I have three classes Main, Database and GUI, When I run the main I get an error and the GUI closes followed by a brief error message which I cannot read, not sure where this is going wrong as i believe it can be a number of issues. Thanks for all your help :)

Here is my main class

```
public class MainApplication {

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static void main(String[] args) {

    VideoStoreGUI window = new VideoStoreGUI();
}
```

}

My Database Class:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class DataBase {

static Connection con = null;
static Statement stmt = null;
static ResultSet rs = null;
static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);



public void close_connection() {
    try
    {
        con.close();
        System.out.println("Database Connections Succesully Closed.");
    } 
    catch (SQLException sqle)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: failed to close the database");
    }
}

public static void addMember(int member_id, String name, String address) // Adding a Member to the Database.
{
    try {
        String str = "INSERT INTO members (member_id, name, address) values(" + member_id + ", '" + name + "', '"
                + address + "');";
        int rows = stmt.executeUpdate(str);

        System.out.println("Success in adding member");

    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Could not add member");
    }
}


public static void initialize_database() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/videostore";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "admin");
        stmt = con.createStatement();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: Failed to connect to database\n" + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public DataBase()
{
    initialize_database();      
}
```

}

and my GUI class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;

public class VideoStoreGUI extends JFrame {
private JFrame frame;

DataBase my_database;
private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textMemberID;
private JTextField textMemberName;
private JTextField textMemberAddress;

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public VideoStoreGUI() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 400);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    tabbedPane.setBounds(10, 31, 232, 240);
    contentPane.add(tabbedPane);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    tabbedPane.addTab("Members", null, panel, null);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    JLabel labelMemberID = new JLabel("Members ID");
    labelMemberID.setBounds(10, 11, 85, 14);
    panel.add(labelMemberID);

    JLabel labelMemberName = new JLabel("Members Name");
    labelMemberName.setBounds(10, 36, 85, 14);
    panel.add(labelMemberName);

    JLabel labelMemberAddress = new JLabel("Members Address");
    labelMemberAddress.setBounds(10, 61, 85, 14);
    panel.add(labelMemberAddress);

    textMemberID = new JTextField();
    textMemberID.setBounds(131, 8, 86, 20);
    panel.add(textMemberID);
    textMemberID.setColumns(10);

    textMemberName = new JTextField();
    textMemberName.setColumns(10);
    textMemberName.setBounds(131, 33, 86, 20);
    panel.add(textMemberName);

    textMemberAddress = new JTextField();
    textMemberAddress.setColumns(10);
    textMemberAddress.setBounds(131, 58, 86, 20);
    panel.add(textMemberAddress);

    JButton buttonAddMember = new JButton("Add Member");
    buttonAddMember.setBounds(10, 86, 102, 23);
    panel.add(buttonAddMember);

    JButton buttonRemoveMember = new JButton("Add Member");
    buttonRemoveMember.setBounds(115, 86, 102, 23);
    panel.add(buttonRemoveMember);

    JButton buttonSearchMember = new JButton("Add Member");
    buttonSearchMember.setBounds(66, 120, 102, 23);
    panel.add(buttonSearchMember);

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    tabbedPane.addTab("Products", null, panel_1, null);
}
```

}

Comment: Could you see the console and post de error if there is one?

Comment: I don't understand how you can not read error message. If you are running this from an IDE error message should be in console, if you are running this from command line you should still see error message. BTW, you are not showing your JFrame in the code. You should call `pack` and then `setVisible(true)` on your GUI.

Comment: Did you add the mysql JDBC driver to the classpath?

Comment: Yes I have the JDBC Driver, the error message pops up for a fraction of a second, the first line "Exception in thread AWT-EventQueue-0" followed by about 40 lines of code?

Comment: Write error messages to console or file instead of showing them in popup window.

Answer (score 0):

I see only one place where you can get popup. You can keep it if you like but add system output and be sure about your message:

```
catch (SQLException sqle) {
        System.out.writeln("Exception:"+sqle);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Could not add member");
    }
```

Based on place of this message I think you have wrong sql or database. I would suggest that you print your sql and results of it too.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason this was not working for me was because I had removed setVisable(true) from the GUI and forgot to add it back to the method, I was then receiving an Error "AWT-EventQueue-0" this was to do with the way my database connection was set up, removing and adding the JDBC driver again resolved this.